# Render simple HTML into docx using docxtpl

Tags: python, docx, python-docx, docxtpl

I'm using python module [`docxtpl`](https://pypi.org/project/docxtpl/) to print data inside a docx template written with `jinja2`.
Works great so far but i need to render in the docx some simple HTML like this:

```
<h2>Some title</h2>
<h4>Lorem&nbsp;ipsum <strong>dolor sit amet</strong>, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, aliquam,
    minima fugiat placeat provident optio nam reiciendis eius beatae quibusdam!</h4>
<p style="font-size: 18px;">The text is derived from Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (On the Ends of Goods
    and Evils, or alternatively [About] The Purposes of Good and Evil). The original passage began: Neque porro
    quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit (Translation: "Neither is
    there <del>anyone</del> who loves grief itself since it is grief and thus wants to obtain it").</p>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test1</td>
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>Test3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem</td>
            <td>Lorem1</td>
            <td>Lorem2</td>
            <td>Lorem3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ipsum</td>
            <td>Ipsum1</td>
            <td>Ipsum2</td>
            <td>Ipsum3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately I can't use `RichText()` from `docxtpl` to render tables and other html stuff.

I tried to come up with some solutions but I want to understand if there are better ways besides, for example, merge one docx generated from html usign [`htmldocx`](https://pypi.org/project/htmldocx/) with the one generated using `docxtpl` or get the content with `python-docx` module from one docx and insert it into the other.

In the worst case scenario, I am also willing to switch to JavaScript/BASH.

Comment: I am dealing with this same issue. Did you ever find a solution within `docxtpl`?

Comment: I'm sorry to say I haven't found a solution yet...

Comment: I am using the workaround suggested by @Synthase. Specifically, I use `docxtpl` for the majority of my document, then for the html-specific content I create a standalone html file, then use `htmldocx` to convert the html file to docx, and then append it back to the main docx using `docxcompose`. Not ideal, but it works for my purposes.

Answer (score 3):

```
from htmldocx import HtmlToDocx

new_parser = HtmlToDocx()
new_parser.parse_html_file("html_filename", "docx_filename")
#Files extensions not needed, but tolerated
```

This should work like a charm to convert html in docx.

Not sure I understand your merge problem. The best would certainly be to have your docx template in html instead. Then once you dumped in a single html file everything you need, you convert to docx.

In case you want to merge/insert docx together or so, you can have a look here: [How do I append new data to existing doc/docx file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261386/how-do-i-append-new-data-to-existing-doc-docx-file-using-python)

Comment: Yeah but... not quite what i'm looking for as I said in the question: better solutions than merge 2 docx generated in different ways? I need to use docxtpl or some module that allowd templating

Comment: That's what I said. You should generate an HTML template, not a docx one. Then you pass the whole html thing in docx at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to accomplish this by using `sub-documents` in docxtpl and `htmldoc`. This solution will give you the flexibility of using a template and use subdoc only for the dynamic HTML that needs to be generated.

```
template = DocxTemplate(template_path)
# Make sub document
desc_document = Document()
new_parser = HtmlToDocx()
new_parser.add_html_to_document("<p>Html here</p>" , desc_document)
desc_result_path = settings.SITE_ROOT+"/my_files/temps/subdoc.docx"
desc_document.save(desc_result_path)
# Render as Subdoc
sub_doc = template.new_subdoc(desc_result_path)
context = {
    'sub_doc': sub_doc,
}
# Generate doc
try:
    template.render(context)
    template.save(local_result_path)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
# UNLINK temp files
shutil.rmtree(settings.SITE_ROOT+"/my_files/temps/")
```

I finally cleared all the subdocuments generated using `shutil`